# SED config-file with single quote

Tags: linux, sed, replace

I have a config file which looks like this:

```
        $this->db_host = 'localhost';
        $this->db_port = '3306';
        $this->db_name = 'database';
        $this->db_user = 'root';
```

Im trying to replace the values between the single quotes with sed env-variables I have set but I cant seem to get it working. My sed command looks like this right now.

```
sed -r -in "s/(db_host *= *\").*/\1$MYSQL_HOST\"/" cfg.php
```

The $MYSQL_HOST-var contains the following string "db".

The config should look like the following after the successful sed command:

```
        $this->db_host = 'db';
        $this->db_port = '3306';
        $this->db_name = 'database';
        $this->db_user = 'root';
```

Maybe you can help me find my error?

Comment: Hey, ive provided the example in the main post, thanks for the fast answer.

Answer (score 1):

This will do it:

```
sed -r "s/(\s*.*db_host =* *').*('.*)/\1$MYSQL_HOST\2/" your_file
```

The ways it's working is as follows:

- I remember the stuff in between the above using `(` and `)`
- Specifically I remember up to and including the first single quote and also
  everything after and including the second single quote. So we remember all
  by the `localhost` bit.
- Then replace with the remembered content `\1` and `\2` and the `$MYSQL_HOST`
  going in between

Once you've confirmed it does what you want, just add the `-i`:

```
sed -ri "s/(\s*.*db_host =* *').*('.*)/\1$MYSQL_HOST\2/" your_file
```